# Java Loop Arraylist and remove when necessary

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, while-loop

I have a ArrayList with coordinates(long and lat). And I want to calculate the distance between the coordinates.

```
for(Winkel winkel: winkels){
            Projection projection = mv.getProjection();
            ArrayList<Winkel> cluster = new ArrayList<Winkel>();

            winkels.remove(winkel);

            for(Winkel item: winkels){                      
                //GetLocations
                if(Math.sqrt(Math.pow((point.x - point1.x), 2) + Math.pow((point.y - point1.y), 2)) < 100){
                    cluster.add(item);
                    winkels.remove(item);
                }       
            }
        }
```

EDIT: I edited the code. If I get the second time to the first for. I get an error:

```
03-08 10:01:27.419: E/AndroidRuntime(10572): 
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{be.oww.app/be.oww.app.WinkelsTabActivity}: 
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{be.oww.app/be.oww.app.MapsTabActivitiy}: 
     java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

03-08 10:01:27.419: E/AndroidRuntime(10572):    
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1821)
```

...

Comment: You're probably not well aware of the `Collection Framework` available in Java.

Comment: As a style point (unrelated to your question), you should probably write methods on Winkel that return X and Y coordinates as Doubles, containing the code `Double.parseDouble(item.getCoordinaten().split(",")[0]) * 1E6` so that you don't have to repeat that snippet every time you need that information.

Comment: Why are there so many answers to a post without a question?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to get a second iterator for the second while loop:

```
 Iterator<Winkel> iItems = winkels.iterator();
 while(iItems.hasNext()){
        Winkel item = iItems.next();
```

With you current code, `winkel` is set to the first item of the collection, then the inner loop runs from the second one to the last. That's probably *not* what you want.

BTW: - you can do the same with for loops:

```
for (Winkel winkel:winkels) {
  Projection projection = mv.getProjection();
  ArrayList<Winkel> cluster = new ArrayList<Winkel>();
  for(Winkel item:winkels){
     Double itemLat = Double.parseDouble(item.getCoordinaten().split(",")[0]) * 1E6;
     // ...
  }
  if(cluster.size()==0){
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact, `next()` does not *remove* anything. The `remove()` function removes. `next()` just gives you the next item.

If you don't want to advance to the next item, don't call `next()`, but remember the previous value in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to have nested loops on the same iterator.

It looks like you want to compare every element of the collection to every other element of the collection. In that case your outer loop should use an iterator on `winkels`, as at present. And in the body of the outer loop, you should obtain a *different* iterator on `winkels` and loop through this second iterator in the inner loop.

(ah... someone else already posted the same answer)

It'll be easier to see the structure if you use the enhanced for loop:

```
for (Winkel winkel : winkels) {

    Projection projection = mv.getProjection();
    ArrayList<Winkel> cluster = new ArrayList<Winkel>();

    for (Winkel otherWinkel : winkels) {
        // do what you need to compare the two Winkels
        // this will be executed N*N times where N is collection size
    }
}
```

(edit: I seem to be cloning someone else's thoughts here)

Comment: I tried your solution. I changed my question. Could you have a look?

Comment: Ah yes. While you're using an Iterator, it'll fail if the underlying Collection changes, other than by the remove() method of that Iterator. In this case you're changing the underlying Collection by calling remove() on a different Iterator on the same Collection. You want to do something like what user1242756 suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the logic you're using, but I would do the loop like this:

```
List<Winkel> toRemove = new ArrayList<Winkel>();
for (int i = 0; i < winkels.size(); i++) {
    Winkel winkel = winkels[i];
    // you don't have to compare a point with itself
    for (int j = i+1; j < winkels.size(); j++) {
        Winkel item = winkels[j];
        // do item stuff here
        if (distance < 100) {
            toRemove.add(winkel);
            break;
        }
    }
    // do winkel stuff here
}
winkels.removeAll(toRemove); // items are removed after the loop
```

PS: I don't think is a good idea to remove objects from a list during the iteration.

Comment: The removing is actualy my problem. The items need to be removed because if the distance is smaller between 2 points. For that coordinate the distance between that point and all other points doesn't need to be calculated anymore.

Comment: I updated the code. You can use a helper list to flag the items to remove. I just said it's not a good idea to remove elements DURING the iteration. :)

Comment: It won't get to removeAll until all elements are compared to all other elements. So the removeAll is of no use right?

Comment: Nope. That's what the 'break' statement is for. You add the element in the list to remove, and it won't be compared anymore.

Comment: Actually the `remove()` method of an iterator is *designed* for removing elements from a list during iteration.

Comment: I didn't say you can't do it. But I think is really hard to find an error later. And using two for statements like this, you will never compare a object with itself and two objects will be compared only one time(compare A->B but not B->A).

Answer (score 0):

The only safe way to remove items from a Collection while looping is via Iterator, otherwise you will get trouble. So, try this:

```
Iterator<Winkel> iterator = winkels.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    Winkel winkel = iterator.next();
    // do something with winkel
    if (condition) {
        iterator.remove(); // removes current winkel from the collection
```